# Disable Wordpress permalinks for images

Tags: wordpress

Whenever I add an image in Wordpress, I notice it creates a neat little direct link to the new images (www.url.example/image_title)

I don't want to expose the images that directly. Is there any way to prevent wordpress creating this 'permalinks'?

(Yoast SEO is installed on my wordpress site)

Comment: when you upload and insert the image you can choose how it will be linked . see answer

Answer (score 0):

When you insert an image ( media ), you can choose the URL or link that would be attached to the image ( read : media )

From Codex :

> **Attachment Page** : Links your inserted image to its WordPress media attachment page.
>
> **Media File**: Links your inserted image directly to the original,full-size version of the file.
>
> **Custom URL**: Allows you to set a custom link URL for your inserted image to > link to when clicked.
>
> **None**: This setting will remove the link completely, rendering the image “un-clickable”.

The options are displayed in the ["Attachment Details"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Inserting_Media_into_Posts_and_Pages#Step_4_.E2.80.93_Attachment_Details:) area and detailed in the codex page ( click the link ) - so just choosing `none` would potentially do what you are asking for ( but you alsso need to consider themes and plugins that might change this default wp behavior )

That being said - you will not be able to easily hide thee URL because anyone with a very basic understanding of wordpress could potentially find the URL `yoursite.tld/wp-istall-folder/wp-content/uploads/...` etc. and that without even mentioning the `inspect element` or `view source` functions ..

You COULD hide the wp-content folder, or change it - but again, the point is that if your images are on the server - they can be easily found ..